# Comparing the Date & Time class in another class JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator, comparable

so earlier this year I was given an assignment at university. The assignment was to create a Car park management system by using OOP procedures. For example, we learnt how to use inheritance, abstract classes and instances. I have already completed and passed this assignment so this question is just for knowledge purposes. One of the tasks was to order the ArrayList of objects in chronological order. To do this, we was taught the comparable/comparator way. However, I could not get my head around it and was unable to do it. The problem was, we had to order a 'DateTime' object which was in a 'Vehicle' object in the arraylist. I am not using a predefined libary for the date and time as it needed to be user entered. 
Thanks.

So first of all here is the abstract Vehicle class.

```
 public abstract class Vehicle{

protected String vehicleID, brand;
protected DateTime datetime;
 }
```

Then i'll include one of the inherited vehicle classes.

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

protected String colour;
protected int numOfDoors;

public Car(String brand, String vehicleID, int numOfDoors, String colour) {
    this.vehicleID = vehicleID;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.numOfDoors = numOfDoors;
    this.colour = colour;
}

public void setColour(String colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
}

public void setvehicleID(String vehicleID) {
    this.vehicleID = vehicleID;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}

public String getColour() {
    return this.colour;
}

public String getVehicleID() {
    return this.vehicleID;
}

public String getBrand() {
    return this.brand;
}

public String toString() {

    return "Car";

}

public int getNumOfDoors() {
    return numOfDoors;
}

public void setNumOfDoors(int numOfDoors) {
    this.numOfDoors = numOfDoors;
}

public DateTime getDatetime() {
    return datetime;
}

public void setDatetime(DateTime datetime) {
    this.datetime = datetime;
}


  }
```

Next up is the dateTime class that does not use a predefined library and is entered in to the console.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class DateTime implements Comparator<DateTime> {

protected int day, month, year, minutes, hours;

public DateTime() {

}

public DateTime(int minutes, int hours, int day, int month, int year) {
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.hours = hours;
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return day+"/"+month+"/"+year + " " + minutes+":"+hours;
}

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}

public void setDay(int day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public int getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(int month) {
    this.month = month;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public int getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}

public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
    this.minutes = minutes;
}

public int getHours() {
    return hours;
}

public void setHours(int hours) {
    this.hours = hours;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(DateTime o) {
    int returnValue = 0;
    if (this.year > o.getYear())
    returnValue = 1;
    else 
        returnValue = -1;
    return returnValue;

}

@Override
public int compare(DateTime o1, DateTime o2) {
 return o1.year - o2.year;
}


}
```

As you can see I have tried to use the comparable and comparator.

Next the instance and the main class

```
 public interface CarParkManager {

public abstract void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle);

public abstract void printVehicleList();

public abstract void deleteVehicle();

public abstract boolean runMenu();
}
```

Main:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;

 import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyCarParkManager implements CarParkManager {

private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles;
private int numSpaces, doors, day, month, year, minutes, hour;
private String brand, vehicleID, colour, engineSize, cargoVolume;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public MyCarParkManager(int vehicleList) {
    vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    this.numSpaces = vehicleList;

}

public void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
    if (vehicles.size() < numSpaces) {

        vehicles.add(vehicle);
        numSpaces--;
        System.out.println("Spaces left: " + numSpaces);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not enough spaces.");
    }

}

@Override
public void deleteVehicle() {
    for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(vehicles.get(i).vehicleID);
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter vehicle ID you wish to delete");
    String idDelete = in.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
        if(vehicles.get(i).vehicleID.equals(idDelete)){
            System.out.println("The " + vehicles.get(i).toString() + " was 
    deleted.");
            vehicles.remove(i);


        }
    }

   }

  @Override
   public void printVehicleList() {

    for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
                Collections.sort(vehicles, new DateTime());
    }

    }

   @Override
   public boolean runMenu() {
    boolean exit = false;
    System.out.println("Please enter desired function");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to add a vehicle");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 to delete a parked vehicle");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 to display already parked vehicles");

    int choice = in.nextInt();
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to add a car");
            System.out.println("Enter 2 to add a van");
            System.out.println("Enter 3 to add a bike");
            int choice2 = in.nextInt();
            switch (choice2) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Please enter brand of car");
                    brand = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter vehicleID");
                    vehicleID = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter number of doors");
                    doors = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter colour of the car");
                    colour = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the minutes of parked 
      vehicle");
                    minutes = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter hour of parked 
      vehicle");
                    hour = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter day");
                    day = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter month");
                    month = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter year");
                    year = in.nextInt();
                    DateTime datetime = new DateTime(minutes, hour, day, month, year);
                    Car c = new Car(brand, vehicleID, doors, colour);
                    c.setDatetime(datetime);
                    addVehicle(c);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Please enter brand of car");
                    brand = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter vehicleID");
                    vehicleID = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter cargoVolume");
                    cargoVolume = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the minutes of parked 
     vehicle");
                    minutes = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter hour of parked 
    vehicle");
                    hour = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter day");
                    day = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter month");
                    month = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter year");
                    year = in.nextInt();
                    DateTime vanDateTime = new DateTime(minutes, hour, day, month, year);
                    Van v = new Van(brand, vehicleID, cargoVolume);
                    v.setDatetime(vanDateTime);
                    addVehicle(v);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Please enter brand of car");
                    brand = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter vehicleID");
                    vehicleID = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter engine size");
                    engineSize = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the minutes of parked vehicle");
                    minutes = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter hour of parked vehicle");
                    hour = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter day");
                    day = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter month");
                    month = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter year");
                    year = in.nextInt();
                    DateTime bikeDateTime = new DateTime(minutes, hour, day, month, year);
                    Bike b = new Bike(brand, vehicleID, engineSize);
                    b.setDatetime(bikeDateTime);
                    addVehicle(b);
                    break;

            }
            break;
        case 2:
            deleteVehicle();
            break;
        case 3:
            printVehicleList();
            break;

    }

    return exit;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CarParkManager carPark = new MyCarParkManager(20);
    boolean exit = false;

    while (!exit) {
        exit = carPark.runMenu();
    }
}

}
```

Here is where I am trying to sort the arraylist. I understand that it's not working because the Arraylist is an Arraylist of object vehicles. I don't understand how I would sort the object using comparable or comparator. Any help would be appericated.

```
 public void printVehicleList() {

        for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
                    Collections.sort(vehicles, new DateTime());
        }

        }
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ..Post only the code which is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compare Vehicles. So you'll need a VehicleComparator, not a DateTime comparator:

```
public class VehicleComparator implements Comparator<Vehicle> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Vehicle o1, Vehicle o2) {
        // now get the two vehicle's dates and compare them
    }
}
```

Then

```
Collections.sort(vehicles, new VehicleComparator());
```

Update:

Also, you don't need a `Comparator` AND a `Comparable`.

A `Comparator` is a standalone class to compare things.  You use that to call `Collections.sort(vehicles, comparator)`.

*Alternatively* you can make things implement `Comparable` themselves (e.g. `Vehicle implements Comparable`).  Then they can effectively compare themselves.  If something implements `Comparable` (this is known as "natural ordering").
When doing it this way, you can call `Collections.sort(vehicles)`.  That version of the sort method expects everything in the list to implement `Comparable`, and so doesn't need a standalone `Comparator` to do that work for it.

You don't need to do both.

Comment: Would i be able to put this in to the abstract class or create a whole new class?

Comment: @jdotHello have updated the answer.  Would have it as a totally standalone class.

Answer (score 0):

You should to implement Comparable interface in your DateTime class and override method compareTo, and compare for sorting.

```
public class DateTime implements Comparator<DateTime>, Comparable<DateTime> {

    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(DateTime dateTime) {
        if (year > dateTime.year) {
            return 1;
        } else if (month > dateTime.month) {
            return 1;
        } ...
    }

    @Override
   public int compare(DateTime dateTime1, DateTime dateTime2) {
       return dateTime1.compareTo(dateTime2)
   }

}
```

I also thing that in contstructor of class DateTime you should to check that hour is between 0 and 23, minutes are between 0 and 59 etc

To sort it in main you should implement Comparable interface in Vehicle class

```
public class VehicleComparator implements Comparator<Vehicle> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Vehicle vehicle1, Vehicle vehicle2) {
        return vehicle1.dateTime.compareTo(vehicle2.dateTime);    
    }
}
```

OR

```
public void printVehicleList() {


 Collections.sort(vehicles, new Comparator<Vehicle>(){
     public int compare(Vehicle v1, Vehicle v2){
         return v1.dateTime.compareTo(v2.dateTime);
     }
});
```

And take care that v1(object which get dateTime fild) != null, otherwise nullPointerException will be.

Comment: i'll give this a go thank you. And yes you are correct with the validations I just haven't done them yet. thanks

Comment: How would you call this from the main class?

Comment: Thank you also If i could choose both answers to be correct I would :)